# RSS on the Windows Phone 7

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, rss

I am developer of Windows phone 7, and I want to ask: if I go to  .xml code, and there is such

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<artists>
<images>
<image size="1">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/17666215.jpg</image>
<image size="2">http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/17666215.jpg</image>
</images>
</artists>
```

So how can I choose the second element there?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to parse this XML file and get the second element value, so you can do that using something like this:

```
XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse("path_to_xml_file");
//you can also pass a the content as a string or a stream reader

XElement image = (from element in xmlDocument.Element("artists").Element("images").Descendants("image")
                          where element.Attribute("size").Value == "2"
                          select element).FirstOrDefault();

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(image.Value);
```

Then add this imports:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

And add a reference to System.Xml.Linq.dll to your project.

I think this link can also be helpful for you: [How to Get XML Node from XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752271/how-to-get-xml-node-from-xdocument)