# c# DataSet with depth more than three

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I want to use an xml-file for storing my program data. The structure of the xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Data>
    <Projects>
        <Project>
            <Name>Name1</Name>
            <Description>Description1</Description>
        </Project>
        <Project>
            <Name>Name2</Name>
            <Description>Description2</Description>
        </Project>
    </Projects>
</Data>
```

I want to use a `DataSet` since it offers the easy reading and writing of xml structures. But the question is, how to read and write the values of the `<Project>`-Nodes? I can access the `<Projects>`-Node, but then i don't know how to continue, since the single Projects aren't tables i guess. So, how can i access the nodes in the depth three (Data->Projects->Project)? I think this must work somehow, since reading the file and outputting it on the console does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then a `DataSet` I suggest you look at using XDocument and XElement instead, since they can offer much better API for accessing items in the XML structure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Another link which may help you get started:

[How to Get XML Node from XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752271/how-to-get-xml-node-from-xdocument)

Comment: Hm... sounds good. I thought it would be easier to use `DataSet`s but it seems not to be the right way. I'll have a look for the classes you (and Daniel) suggested. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You better try that with a class Data that has a list of objects Project it is easier to serialize/deserialize . I dont think its easier to read/write xml with a dataset .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `DataSet` isn't the right way for you to go. It is not intended to be a general purpose mechanism for reading and writing arbitrary XML.

If you're using .NET Framework 4 or later, I suggest using [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) instead of `DataSet`.

If you're using an older .NET Framework version then there are plenty of other options, including [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx), [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx), and [XmlSerlializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx). Which to choose depends on where your data is coming from and how you want to process it.