# How can I access a single XML element's value using C#.net web-pages with WebMatrix?

Tags: c#, xml, razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I've looked at a lot of resources, done a lot of research, and tried many "best-guesses" to access a single element at a time using WebMatrix with C#, web-pages, however nothing I am trying is getting through.

Consider a simple xml document that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <requisitionData>
        <element1>I am element 1</element1>
        <element2>I am element 2</element2>
    </requisitionData>
</root>
```

I know I can use a foreach loop, like so:

```
@using System.Xml.Linq

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/User_Saves/cradebaugh/testFile.xml"));

foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("requisitionData"))
{
    @element.Value
}
```

And that, of course, works fine.  But what if I simply wanted to store the single element, `<element1>`'s value in a string variable?

I've looked here (link below), but I can't make heads or tails of this code (it barely even looks like C# to me, but then again, I'm so new to parsing XML...):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b14ce4d1-77f1-420d-ad91-0989794a1d45/

I've also checked here: [How to Get XML Node from XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752271/how-to-get-xml-node-from-xdocument)

But the code shown makes no sense to me here either.  I keep thinking there must be a simpler way to do this, hopefully without learning a whole new querying approach.

---------------------------------THINGS I'VE TRIED---------------------------------

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/User_Saves/cradebaugh/testFile.xml"));

string element = doc.Descendants("requisitionData").Descendants("element1").Value;
```

**Error I receive:** "missing using directive or assembly reference

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/User_Saves/cradebaugh/testFile.xml"));

XElement element = doc.Descendants("element1");
string val = element.Value;
```

**Error I receive:**  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I have, indeed, tried other things, but I get pretty much the same errors as shown above. Am I making this harder than it is, or am I oversimplifying it?

-------------------------UPDATE------------------------------

I was able to get this to work:

```
string element = doc.Element("root").Element("requisitionData").Element("element1").Value;

@element
```

However, one thing that concerns me about this approach is that `.Element` selects the 'first' match, so in an xml document that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <requisitionData>
        <element1>I am element 1</element1>
        <element2>I am element 2</element2>
    </requisitionData>
    <requisitionData>
        <element1>I am element 1</element1>
        <element2>I am element 2</element2>
    </requisitionData>
</root>
```

How could I access the second occurrence of `<element1>`?

Comment: After having this issue resolved for a couple of days (thanks to the answer below), I'm gonna have to say that using XPathSelectElement(s) seems to be the way to go. XPath is powerful (way more than I realized) accurate, and completely flexible, whether I want a single element or many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@using System.Xml.Linq

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/User_Saves/cradebaugh/testFile.xml"));

foreach (XElement element in doc.Element("root").Element("requisitionData").Descendants())
{
    string value = element.Value;
}
```

or with XPath:

```
@using System.Xml.Linq
@using System.Xml.XPath

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/User_Saves/cradebaugh/testFile.xml"));

foreach (XElement element in doc.XPathSelectElement("//requisitionData").Descendants())
{
    string value = element.Value;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

And if you wanted to select for example the second `<element1>` node from your updated example:

```
string value = doc.XPathSelectElement("//requisitionData[2]/element1").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am explicitly wanting only a single element, thus alleviating the need for a code 'loop'

Comment: Also, I don't see how this selects a single element. There is more than one result that will be iterated through, given the foreach loop conditions.

Comment: Which particular node in the XML do you want? You could use the XPath example I have shown in my answer to get any specific node you like. For example if you wanted to get the value of the first `<element1>` node you would have written `string value = doc.XPathSelectElements("//requisitionData/element1").First().Value;`.

Comment: I certainly have no problem studying XPath, but let me express my thoughts this way:  If I wanted to do this "client-side" (which I really don't) I could simply use a jQuery(CSS) selector to grab any single element by id, or grab multiples by class (or tag name for that matter) and iterate through them using .length. I feel like I have full control over exactly which elements I want to select and gather the data from. I would love to achieve this level of control "server-side" if possible (I'm sure it is, at least with XPath, although it may not be as simple).

Comment: Until your examples, though, I had no idea how to use XPath with C#.net, so, again, thank you for that!

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve and what problems are you encountering. The `doc.XPathSelectElements("//requisitionData/element1")` expression will give you a list of all `<element1>` nodes. Isn't what you were asking for? Also I don't see what client side CSS has to do with the question here. All the examples are using server side code.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have confused you, but the question is pretty clear, what I am really asking is how to select a "single" element (not a list, not a collection, not all `<element1>`s but a single individual `<element1>` You're right "client-side" has nothing to do with this, except that I was simply using it as an example to explain the level of control I would like to achieve "server-side". Is there a way to use XPath (or any other C#.net method) to select a single element by 'id' or 'class', by any chance? Again, sorry for the confusion, but the original question states "single element"

Comment: Like this: `doc.XPathSelectElement("//requisitionData/element1")`. And if you wanted the second `element1` then simply adapt your XPath expression: `doc.XPathSelectElement("//requisitionData[2]/element1")`. I have updated my answer to provide you with a specific example.