# Passing extra flag in XML request parameter when a request parameter value is 1 in .net core web api

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-core-webapi

In .net core web api I was given a task to add a extra parameter in the XML request which checks for another parameter if its 1 then my parameter should pass as

```
<old_parameter>1</old_parameter> then 
<my_parameter>Y</my_parameter>this I need to pass.
```

Just wanted to know how this is achieved and which files or code needs to be checked.

Any tutorial or refence might help a lot.

Comment: Use an XML Library to read existing XML and modify.  We really need the entire xml structure to help. There are lots of ways of modify and it also depends on the default namespace.

Comment: You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903671/how-can-i-access-a-single-xml-elements-value-using-c-net-web-pages-with-webmat) to learn how to read element in xml and refer this [link](https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/evergreen-assets/safelinks/1/atp-safelinks.html) to learn how to add element in xml