# [XML via VB]Same value and tag name but how do i determine?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Lets say this is my default code:

```
<panel>
 <fontstyle>A</fontstyle>
 <fontsize>12</fontsize>
 <location>100,100</location>
</panel>
```

and when I add in another tag:

```
<programsetting>
    <panel>
        <fontstyle>A</fontstyle>
        <fontsize>12</fontsize>
        <location>100,100</location>
      </panel>
    <panel>
        <fontstyle>B</fontstyle>
        <fontsize>12</fontsize>
        <location>100,100</location>
      </panel>
 </programsetting>
```

So we have 2 same tag names within the group but how do i determine to get B rather than A since I have both the same group name and data name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what technique you are currently using but you could use an xpath query ([xpath query](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)).

depending on the selection criteria you could use

```
/programsetting/panel[last()]
```

to get the last element or

```
/programsetting/panel[fontstyle="B"]
```

to get the element with a certain fontstyle.

Comment: Using Visual Basic 2008. Basic my combobox there's is only 1 value and that's called 'Panel'. So once I select 'panel' then click on load to datagridview and it will post the data to DGV. 
So this is mine button code:
ds.ReadXml(filepath)

Comment: erm what combobox? you need to provide more information on what you are trying to achieve and how you are doing it if you want some serious help

Answer (score 0):

[How to Get XML Node from XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752271/how-to-get-xml-node-from-xdocument)
It is on c# but you can easily convert it.