# Getting the attribute value from two XML nodes with same data

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

First off, I'm sorry for the name. I couldn't think of a way to describe my issue in a question form. But this is what I'm trying to do.

Here is what my xml is looking like:

```
<Settings>
  <Display_Settings>
    <Screen>
      <Name Name="Screen" />
      <ScreenTag Tag="Screen Tag" />
      <LocalPosition X="12" Y="81" Z="28" />
      <Width Width="54" />
      <Height Height="912" />
    </Screen>
    <Camera_Name Name="Camera">
      <CameraTag Tag="Camera Tag" />
      <LocalPosition X="354" Y="108" Z="Z Local Position" />
      <Far Far="98" />
      <Near Near="16" />
      <FOV FOV="78" />
      <AspectRatio AspectRatio="1" />
      <ScreenDistance ScreenDistance="2" />
    </Camera_Name>
  </Display_Settings>
</Settings>
```

What I want is to access the attribute values stored within my local position node. I got some help with this and I can access the screens local position attribute value with this code:

```
  var xdoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Test.xml");
  int x = int)xdoc.Descendants("LocalPosition").First().Attribute("X");
```

This happily returns 12 when I debug it. But, I also want to my cameras local position to be out putted as well.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Comment: This will help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752271/how-to-get-xml-node-from-xdocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab Camera and Screen position using `Descendants` and then accessing it components with `Attribute`. Code examples are given below:

```
var cameraPosition = xdoc.Descendants("Camera_Name")
                         .First()
                         .Element("LocalPosition");

var screenPosition = xdoc.Descendants("Screen")
                         .First()
                         .Element("LocalPosition");


//parsing and displaying data
int cameraX = int.Parse(cameraPosition.Attribute("X").Value);
int cameraY = int.Parse(cameraPosition.Attribute("Y").Value);
Console.WriteLine ("camera pos: X={0}; Y={1}", cameraX, cameraY);

int screenX = int.Parse(screenPosition.Attribute("X").Value);
int screenY = int.Parse(screenPosition.Attribute("Y").Value);
Console.WriteLine ("screen pos: X={0}; Y={1}", screenX, screenY);
```

prints:

```
screen pos: X=12; Y=81
camera pos: X=354; Y=108
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use XPath you can target the nodes and retrieve them in to an iterator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea193ac.aspx