# Error in Xml parsing with C# XmlDocument class

Tags: c#, xml

When I add xmls attribute to my root element this code through a exception at third line " Object reference not set to an instance of an object" but after removing xmls attribute from root element it  it works fine.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("file.xml");    
MessageBox.Show(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("person/name").InnerText);
```

here is my xmlfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<person xmlns="namespace path">
<name>myname</name>
</person>
```

I want to know why it does not works after adding xmlns attribute to my root element. Do I have to use another method for parsing ?.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**
>
> If the XPath expression does not include a prefix, it is assumed
> that the namespace URI is the empty namespace. If your XML includes a
> default namespace, you must still add a prefix and namespace URI to
> the XmlNamespaceManager; otherwise, you will not get a node selected.
> For more information, see Select Nodes Using XPath Navigation.

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("something", "http://or.other.com/init");
XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("something:person/name", ns);
```

Comment: Almost, treemonkey: XmlNode node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("something:person/name", ns);

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **namespace messenger to resolve namespaces** to your xml file.

Consider this example

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <person xmlns="http://www.findpersonName.com"> // Could be any namespace
      <name>myname</name>
  </person>
```

and in your code

```
         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("file.xml");

        //Create an XmlNamespaceManager for resolving namespaces.
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://www.findpersonName.com");
        MessageBox.Show(doc.SelectSingleNode("//ab:name", nsmgr).InnerText);
```

Comment: i did not created this xml file and i did not know about namespace so is it necessary that the namespace should be  in my system.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using `XDocument` and `Linq` to process your XML document.

The following example provides a rough example:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml"); 
var personNames = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("person").Descendants("name") select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

[How to Get XML Node from XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/752271/how-to-get-xml-node-from-xdocument)