# Extracting specific data from an xml file using xdocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get the relevant data from my xml file. So for example I wish to select all of the data from the element called Roker Park, from the venue element. How do I only select that data and not the rest of it? This is my xdocument

```
<Funrun>
    <Venue> 
        <Name>Roker Park</Name>
        <Runner> 
            <Charity>Cancer Research</Charity>
            <Firstname>Roger</Firstname>
            <Lastname>Malibu</Lastname>
            <Sponsorship>550</Sponsorship>
        </Runner>
        <Runner>
            <Charity>Arthritis UK</Charity>
            <Firstname>Adam</Firstname>
            <Lastname>White</Lastname>
            <Sponsorship>340</Sponsorship>
        </Runner>
        <Venue> 
            <Name>Victoria Park</Name>
            <Runner> 
                <Charity>Against Malaria Foundation</Charity>
                <Firstname>Rob</Firstname>
                <Lastname>Tate</Lastname>
                <Sponsorship>850</Sponsorship>
            </Runner>
            <Runner>
                <Charity>Fred Follows Foundation</Charity>
                <Firstname>Peter</Firstname>
                <Lastname>Jackson</Lastname>
                <Sponsorship>500</Sponsorship>
            </Runner>
        </Venue>
</Funrun>
```

The code I've got so far selects all of venues data so I get Victoria Parks as well as Rokers, this is the code I've got so far:

```
List<string> VenueNames = new List<string>();
List<string> VenueDataList = new List<string>();

var doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
var doc2 = XDocument.Load("XMLFile2.xml");
var doc3 = XDocument.Load("XMLFile3.xml");

var combinedunique = doc.Descendants("Venue")
                      .Union(doc2.Descendants("Venue"))
                      .Union(doc3.Descendants("Venue"));

foreach (XElement element in combinedunique.DescendantsAndSelf("Venue"))
{
    VenueNames.Add(element.Element("Name").Value.ToString());
}

if (Convert.ToString(lstboxVenues.SelectedItem) == VenueNames.ElementAt(0))
{
    foreach (XElement element in combinedunique.DescendantsAndSelf("Firstname"))   
    {
        VenueDataList.Add(element.Value);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VenueDataList.Count; i++)
    {
        lstboxVenueData.Items.Add(VenueDataList.ElementAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you don't have closing `</Venue>` tag in xml sample

Comment: Here is a similar answer that should get you what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752271/how-to-get-xml-node-from-xdocument

Comment: Can you please clarify what data from given xml you want to get?

Comment: I do have a </Venue> tag I just accidentally didnt copy it across, sorry. The data I want to get is the Charity, Firstname, Lastname and Sponsorship values from the Venue Roker Park, not from Victoria Park.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting all venue names:

```
List<strgin> VenueNames = combindedunique.Select(v => (string)v.Element("Name")).ToList();
```

Output:

```
[
  "Roker Park",
  "Victoria Park"
]
```

Getting first names by given venue name:

```
string venueName = "Victoria Park"; // name you want to search by
List<string> VenueDataList =
      combindedunique.Where(v => (string)v.Element("Name") == venueName)
                     .Elements("Runner")
                     .Select(r => (string)r.Element("Firstname"))
                     .ToList();
```

Output:

```
[
  "Rob",
  "Peter"
]
```